# vCenter 6.7 High Availability. How to priortize host restart

Tags: vmware-vcenter

We run a VMWare data center with vCenter 6. We recently enabled High Availability on a 3-host cluster in our test environment.

If one cluster fails, the other 2 don't have the resources to take on all of the failed-over VMs. Some of them will remain powered off. Is it possible to prioritize which VMs fail over first?

For example, say a host hold a Windows domain controller, a Git repository, and a Windows deployment server. If that host fails, we definitely want DC and Git online right away. We're not worried if the deployment server stays offline.

In that scenario, how would we ensure the DC and repo get a higher priority than the deployment server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In the vCenter GUI, select your cluster.
- In  the `Configure` tab, select `VM Overrides`.
- Select `Add`.

Repeat until you're happy:

- Select an important VM and `Next`.
- In the `Add VM override` dialog, check `VM Restart Priority` and select `High` or `Highest`, making sure that `Start next priority VMs when` defaults to `Resources allocated`.
- Confirm the changes.

OR

- Select an unimportant VM and `Next`.
- In the `Add VM override` dialog, check `VM Restart Priority` and select `Low` or `Disabled`, making sure that `Start next priority VMs when` defaults to `Resources allocated`.
- Confirm the changes.

Comment: (...But it is better to have "n+1" resources if you can afford it, of course...)